# Remove blank column in CSV with Azure Logic App

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, azure-logic-apps

I have a CSV file on a SFTP which has 13 columns, but annoyingly the last one has no data or header, so basically there is an extra comma at the end of every record:

```
PGR,Concession ,Branch ,Branch Name ,Date ,Receipt ,Ref/EAN,Till No ,Qty , Price  , Discount , Net Price  ,
```

I want to use Logic App to remove the last 13th column and resave the file in a BLOB storage.  I've got as far as reading the file from SFTP and storing the entire text in a variable, then using select to get only the columns I need, but beyond that I can't work out how to export all the records onto 1 clean csv file in BLOB.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to process each row in the array and remove the last comma one by one.  As you remove it, add the result to a new array variable.  This is the basis of the flow ...

[image: Flow]

This expression is the main worker and it's the thing that will remove the last character of each row ...

```
substring(items('For_each'), 0, add(length(items('For_each')), -1))
```

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

This is the definition of the Logic App.  Drop it in to your tenant and see how it works.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_string_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Result String",
                            "value": "@if(equals(length(items('For_each')), 0), '', concat(substring(items('For_each'), 0, add(length(items('For_each')), -1)), '\r\n'))"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('CSV Data')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Result_String": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "repetitions": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_CSV_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "CSV Data",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                "Header1,Header2,Header3,",
                                "Test1.1,Test1.2,Test1.3,",
                                "Test2.1,Test2.2,Test2.3,",
                                "",
                                "Test3.1,Test3.2,Test3.3,",
                                ""
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Cleansed_CSV_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Cleansed CSV Data",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_CSV_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Result_String": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Result String",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Cleansed_CSV_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Result",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "@variables('Result String')"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks looks like my file has an extra blank record at the end which is causing an issue at the "Append to Cleansed CSV Data" step "The 'start index' for function 'substring' must be equal to or greater than zero and must be less than '0' which is the length of the string."
I can replicate it with your LogicApp if the initial variable changes to [
                                "Test1.1,Test1.2,Test1.3,",
                                "Test2.1,Test2.2,Test2.3,",
                                "Test3.1,Test3.2,Test3.3,",
                                ""
                            ]

Comment: Ok, but that’s a different thing. My answer is still the correct one. The issue you’re facing is nothing to do with your question, it’s in addition and another thing you’re facing. It doesn’t change the answer. Make sense?

Comment: Yeah 100%, was just wondering if you had any idea how to solve this too, I'll raise another question instead, thanks for you help!

Comment: Actually there was one more thing about your solution, at the end of it when I tried to create blob it doesn't allow me to use the Cleansed variable as the content, any reason why that might be?

Comment: Oh ok, you're writing to blob.  I've updated the definition in the answer with an additional variable which is a string variable.  That variable is appended to each time with a line break.  It also checks for blank lines in the CSV and doesn't include them. 
 See if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks @Skin, although my header row has now moved somewhere lower in the Result String variable.  For example if I change Initialize CSV Data to 
`[
  "Header1,Header2,Header3,",
  "Test1.1,Test1.2,Test1.3,",
  "Test2.1,Test2.2,Test2.3,",
  "Test3.1,Test3.2,Test3.3,",
  "Test4.1,Test4.2,Test4.3,",
  "Test5.1,Test5.2,Test5.3,",
  "Test6.1,Test6.2,Test6.3,"
]`
I get this as my final Result String Variable
`Test6.1,Test6.2,Test6.3
Test3.1,Test3.2,Test3.3
Test2.1,Test2.2,Test2.3
Test4.1,Test4.2,Test4.3
Test1.1,Test1.2,Test1.3
Header1,Header2,Header3
Test5.1,Test5.2,Test5.3`

Comment: Oh, change the FOR loop so it doesn't run in parallel.  Go to the settings of the FOR EACH and turn **Concurrency Control** on and set the **Degree of parallelism** to 1.  See if that fixes it for you.  We'll get there eventually.  :-)

Comment: Have updated the definition in my answer.

Comment: Think that's done the trick!  Thank you so much, have learnt a few new tricks in Logic App now!